# Dynamic SQL--Nested Replace() Function

Tags: sql, t-sql, dynamic-sql, edi

I want to replace special characters in an `item_desc`. This data is getting transformed into EDI, and I haven't `~` or `*` in the description.

Would the code below work? I have double ticks because it's dynamic SQL.

```
replace(replace(sd.item_desc,''*'',''''),
    sd.item_desc,''~'','''') item_desc
```

Comment: Sample input and output will help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it won't work. Try this:

```
replace(replace(sd.item_desc, ''*'', ''''), ''~'', '''') item_desc
```

First parameter of `replace` is a string, as you know, so you need to provide string in outer `replace`, which would be string returned by the inner `replace`.

Comment: Thanks! I knew the syntax was off, just wasn't seeing it.